# How to find your current location without Core Location?

Tags: ios, core-location

I have developed a location based application using the Google Maps SDK. How can I get a current location without location services (i.e location services Don't allow)? I want to get a current location using cellular data or WiFi network.

Answer (score 3):

To get the location using wifi or cellular, you must use CoreLocation and have permission from the user to get their location.

As per [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/):

> For the services you use, configure any properties associated with that service accurately. Core Location manages power aggressively by turning off hardware when it is not needed. **For example, setting the desired accuracy for location events to one kilometer gives the location manager the flexibility to turn off GPS hardware and rely solely on the WiFi or cell radios, which can lead to significant power savings**.

So CoreLocation decides where to get the location, given the accuracy you require for your app. But you still need permission.

If you just need the country or so, the IP-based approach suggested by Dan in his answer might be good enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. And more to the point would Apple allow such a thing? Potentially not, depends how you go about it.

However one thought I had, is that you could look online to see if there is some online service which can pass you your current location with a simple API request. It would most likely use the users IP address to figure out where you are. However if the user is using something as simple as a VPN then this wouldn't return the correct location back. Lastly, if you use a method like this then make sure you prompt the user for their permission FIRST, otherwise Apple will reject your app.

**Update**

This is a free service which is worth a look at: http://www.ipaddresslabs.com/IP-GeoLoc-ip-address-geolocation-locator-lookup-database-software-geography-country-region-state-county-province-city-postal-zip-code-metro-area-code-latitude-longitude@IP-GeoLoc

It allows you to pass the users IP address in return for their current location. I believe it passes back a simple JSON file which is very easy to parse. You can then use the parsed location information as is appropriate in your app.

The limitation here being that if the user doesn't have an internet connection then this won't work. So if your in the middle of a forest or something, then this may not be the best option.

You really should use `CoreLocation`, it uses GPS and will return you a pretty accurate set of co-ordinates.

Answer (score -1):

You can get away with not having to implement the Core Location's framework, by using CLLocationManager  which is technically apart of Core Location along with MKMapViewDelegate.

Specifically  the did update userLocation function implementing latitude, longitude, center, span, and region to find your current location.

Don't forget to add the "Privacy - Location when in use usage description" permission as well in the info.plist file.

Comment: If it's technically part of `CoreLocation` why would you suggest it?